# Haskell/GHC performance of `any`/`all`

Tags: performance, haskell, linked-list, fold, any

I wrote quantification functions `exists`, `forall`, and `none` for Haskell's build-in `[]` list data type. On multiple occasions, these seemed to prove much more efficient than `Prelude`/`Data.List`s `any` and `all`. I naively suspect that this performance is due to `any` and `all` being implemented using Θ(n) folds. Since I am relatively new to Haskell, I think I must be mistaken, or that there would be a good reason for this phenomenon.

From `Data.Foldable`:

```
-- | Determines whether any element of the structure satisfies the predicate.
any :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool
any p = getAny #. foldMap (Any #. p)

-- | Determines whether all elements of the structure satisfy the predicate.
all :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool
all p = getAll #. foldMap (All #. p)
```

My implementations:

```
exists :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
exists _    []                   = False
exists pred (x : xs) | pred x    = True
                     | otherwise = exists pred xs
```

and

```
forall pred  =  not . exists (not . pred)
none pred  =  not . exists pred  =  forall (not . pred)
```

Eliminating boolean inversions:

```
forall, none :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool

forall _    []                   = True
forall pred (x : xs) | pred x    = forall pred xs
                     | otherwise = False

none _    []                   = True
none pred (x : xs) | pred x    = False
                   | otherwise = none pred xs
```

`all`:

```
time                 327.8 μs   (322.4 μs .. 333.0 μs)
                     0.997 R²   (0.996 R² .. 0.998 R²)
mean                 328.7 μs   (324.1 μs .. 334.2 μs)
std dev              16.95 μs   (14.63 μs .. 22.02 μs)
```

and `forall`:

```
time                 113.2 μs   (111.2 μs .. 115.0 μs)
                     0.997 R²   (0.996 R² .. 0.998 R²)
mean                 112.0 μs   (110.0 μs .. 113.9 μs)
std dev              6.333 μs   (5.127 μs .. 7.896 μs)
```

Performance measured using criterion's `nf`.

---

As anticipated, I did not reinvent the fold, but had underestimated compiler flags, and naively did not expect `-O2` to make such drastic overall difference compared to default optimization level performance, nor the optimization effectiveness disparity between the individual custom-wrote and library formulations. Many highly effective specialized standard function optimizations evidently kick in only when explicitly enabled.

The "performance" section of the Haskell tag info emphasizes importance of optimization level compiler flags when testing code efficiency. It is generally advised to trust the sophistication of library function implementations, and, rather than rewire `RULES` pragmas or reformulate basic forms, to try exploiting already cultivated optimization potential.

Comment: If you want to reason about the performance of the code on this level, you probably should look at the core. The performance gap has nothing to do with asymptotics (how could it? your functions are clearly O(n) as well) - my guess is it would be due to lack of inlining in `Foldable` functions. All your functions are equivalent to `foldr f z` for some `f`, `z`, and `List.foldr` would probably inline even when `Foldable.foldr` doesn't.

Comment: Could you share your benchmarks?

Comment: I'm failing to reproduce this with simple `all` / `forall` . Unsurprisingly, where fusible operations are involved it is no contest: http://sprunge.us/RQdO Of course you could write fusion rules for `forall` and company.

Comment: @Michael I get results similar to those of Georg with `-O0`, and similar to yours with `-O2`.

Comment: @duplode which begs the question: did Georg use optimization?

Comment: @duplode thanks that explains it. The bench context made me take it for granted we were turning up optimization.

Comment: please read the haskell tag info section re performance questions

Comment: You should also try out `-O`. It compiles *much* faster than `-O2`, and the code it produces is often quite good enough.

Comment: Also, note that basically all the `Foldable` functions can have serious performance problems when used with the "wrong" containers. `Foldable` is a "leaky" abstraction: you really have to think about what you're using it with. Some people are trying to improve matters, but it seems inherently difficult.

Comment: @dfeuer it is so in general, but as it happens the program I linked I cannot observe to take more time with -O2 than  -O but sometimes less.

Comment: @dfeuer the advice is good for libraries, but if it is just a question of compiling a Main module, a habit of using -O2 seems to me to have all arguments in its favor, and so it is for standard uses of `criterion`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I find it instructive to re-implement `any` in the various ways:

```
import Prelude hiding (any)
import Criterion.Main
import Data.Foldable (foldMap)
import Data.Monoid
```

Your `exists`:

```
exists :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
exists _ [] = False
exists pred (x : xs)
    = if pred x
      then True
      else exists pred xs
```

A version using `(||)`:

```
existsOr :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
existsOr _ [] = False
existsOr pred (x : xs) = pred x || existsOr pred xs
```

Using `foldr`:

```
any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
any pred = foldr ((||) . pred) False
```

Using `foldr` and `Any`:

```
anyF :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
anyF pred = getAny . foldr (mappend . (Any . pred)) mempty
```

Using `foldMap` and `Any`:

```
anyFM :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
anyFM pred = getAny . foldMap (Any . pred)
```

Benchmarks with `ghc -O0`:

```
benchmarking exists
time                 1.552 μs   (1.504 μs .. 1.593 μs)
                     0.989 R²   (0.983 R² .. 0.993 R²)
mean                 1.482 μs   (1.427 μs .. 1.545 μs)
std dev              196.1 ns   (168.8 ns .. 229.2 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 93% (severely inflated)

benchmarking existsOr
time                 2.699 μs   (2.616 μs .. 2.768 μs)
                     0.992 R²   (0.988 R² .. 0.995 R²)
mean                 2.629 μs   (2.554 μs .. 2.704 μs)
std dev              277.8 ns   (235.8 ns .. 351.1 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 89% (severely inflated)

benchmarking any
time                 5.551 μs   (5.354 μs .. 5.777 μs)
                     0.990 R²   (0.986 R² .. 0.995 R²)
mean                 5.553 μs   (5.395 μs .. 5.750 μs)
std dev              584.2 ns   (447.5 ns .. 835.5 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 88% (severely inflated)

benchmarking anyF
time                 7.330 μs   (7.081 μs .. 7.612 μs)
                     0.988 R²   (0.982 R² .. 0.994 R²)
mean                 7.502 μs   (7.272 μs .. 7.762 μs)
std dev              848.2 ns   (712.6 ns .. 1.022 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 89% (severely inflated)

benchmarking anyFM
time                 5.668 μs   (5.451 μs .. 6.008 μs)
                     0.987 R²   (0.975 R² .. 0.996 R²)
mean                 5.807 μs   (5.659 μs .. 5.975 μs)
std dev              542.5 ns   (446.4 ns .. 721.8 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 86% (severely inflated)
```

Your version (`exists`) is indeed the fastest, and the `foldr` versions are rather slow.

With `ghc -O2`, your version (`exists`) is the slowest, and all other functions are nearly equally fast to each other:

```
benchmarking exists
time                 753.5 ns   (725.4 ns .. 779.9 ns)
                     0.990 R²   (0.986 R² .. 0.995 R²)
mean                 762.4 ns   (737.0 ns .. 787.0 ns)
std dev              82.47 ns   (66.79 ns .. 105.1 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 91% (severely inflated)

benchmarking existsOr
time                 491.5 ns   (478.2 ns .. 503.2 ns)
                     0.994 R²   (0.992 R² .. 0.996 R²)
mean                 494.5 ns   (481.1 ns .. 512.9 ns)
std dev              54.97 ns   (42.54 ns .. 80.34 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 92% (severely inflated)

benchmarking any
time                 461.2 ns   (442.0 ns .. 479.7 ns)
                     0.989 R²   (0.985 R² .. 0.993 R²)
mean                 456.0 ns   (439.3 ns .. 476.3 ns)
std dev              60.04 ns   (47.27 ns .. 89.47 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 94% (severely inflated)

benchmarking anyF
time                 436.9 ns   (415.8 ns .. 461.0 ns)
                     0.978 R²   (0.967 R² .. 0.988 R²)
mean                 450.8 ns   (430.1 ns .. 472.6 ns)
std dev              70.64 ns   (57.04 ns .. 85.92 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 96% (severely inflated)

benchmarking anyFM
time                 438.9 ns   (426.9 ns .. 449.5 ns)
                     0.993 R²   (0.989 R² .. 0.996 R²)
mean                 435.8 ns   (421.4 ns .. 447.6 ns)
std dev              45.32 ns   (36.73 ns .. 58.74 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 90% (severely inflated)
```

If one looks into the simplified Core code (`ghc -O2 -ddump-simpl`), one sees that there are no `foldr`s anymore (with `-O0`, everything is still in there, `fold`s included).

I would thus venture to say that your code is faster (in the un-optimized version, `-O0`) than the library code, because it is simpler (for the potential price of being less general). The optimized library code is faster than your version, since it is written in a way that its optimization potential is recognized by the compiler. (admittedly, this is a bit of guess work)